# PHP: Error when call function from another function 500 internal server error

Tags: php, function

i don't find error when call a function from another function like this:

**FUNCTIONS PHP**

```
class DB_Functions extends DB_Connect{

    private $dbConnect = "";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbConnect = $this->pdo_connect();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->dbConnect = null;
    }

    public function actionOnProfile() {

        //MORE CODE
        $id = $this->dataActionProfile['id'];
        $nombre = $this->dataActionProfile['nombre'];
        $descrip = $this->dataActionProfile['descrip'];

        updateprofile($nombre, $descrip, $id);
    }

    function updateprofile($nombre, $descrip, $id) {
        $sql = "UPDATE cat_perfiles SET Nombre = :nom, Descripcion = :des WHERE Id = :id";

        $result = $this->dbConnect->prepare($sql) or die ($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':nom',$nombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':des',$descrip,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if (!$result->execute()) {
            return false; 
        }

        $jsonErrorProfile = array();
        $jsonErrorProfile['success'] = 'success';
        return $jsonErrorProfile;
    }
}
```

Error is when use **updateprofile($nombre, $descrip, $id);**

Error: **500 Internal Server Error**

Comment: Try checking your error log file for the actual error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to call `$this->updateprofile(...);`

In php, apart from C++, C#, Java, etc - you need always to specify `$this->`

Comment: Sure!! Now i will see because return null.. but, work :) Thanks